# SQL DATEFROMPARTS - Fails on YEAR(GETDATE())

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm trying to create several date variables based on an original value, but with the current year.  The only code I can get to run seems overly complex and gives me inaccurate results:

```
, DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, o.AnnualReviewDate),
  DATEADD(YEAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-1900,0)) AS ARDateCurr
DATEADD(DAY,DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, o.AnnualReviewDate)+30,
  DATEADD(YEAR,YEAR(GETDATE())-1900,0)) AS ARDatePlus30
```

Why does:

```
DECLARE @Now AS DATE = GETDATE()
DECLARE @Year AS INT = DATEPART(YEAR,@Now)
...
, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Now),MONTH(o.AnnualReviewDate)-1,
DAY(o.AnnualReviewDate)) AS ARDateMin30
```

give me the error message:

'Cannot construct data type date, some of the arguments have values which are not valid.'

[image: Here's an example of what I'm getting now - you can see that the days of the month are off.]

Comment: `MONTH(o.AnnualReviewDate)-1` -- what if the month is January?

Comment: What is the value that causes the error?

Comment: The value that causes the error is YEAR(GETDATE()) or YEAR(@Now).  It runs fine if I use YEAR(o.AnnualReviewDate), but that doesn't help out the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, are these the values you're looking for:

```
declare @t table (AnnualReviewDate datetime)
insert into @t (AnnualReviewDate) values
('20121004'),('20090924'),('20101007'),('20141008'),('20090508'),
('20120229')

select
    AnnualReviewDate,
    r.ARCurrDue,
    DATEADD(day,-30,ARCurrDue) as ARDateMin30,
    DATEADD(day,30,ARCurrDue) as ARDatePlus30
from @t t
cross apply (SELECT DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,AnnualReviewDate,GETDATE())
             ,AnnualReviewDate) as ARCurrDue) r
```

Results:

```
AnnualReviewDate        ARCurrDue               ARDateMin30             ARDatePlus30
----------------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
2012-10-04 00:00:00.000 2015-10-04 00:00:00.000 2015-09-04 00:00:00.000 2015-11-03 00:00:00.000
2009-09-24 00:00:00.000 2015-09-24 00:00:00.000 2015-08-25 00:00:00.000 2015-10-24 00:00:00.000
2010-10-07 00:00:00.000 2015-10-07 00:00:00.000 2015-09-07 00:00:00.000 2015-11-06 00:00:00.000
2014-10-08 00:00:00.000 2015-10-08 00:00:00.000 2015-09-08 00:00:00.000 2015-11-07 00:00:00.000
2009-05-08 00:00:00.000 2015-05-08 00:00:00.000 2015-04-08 00:00:00.000 2015-06-07 00:00:00.000
2012-02-29 00:00:00.000 2015-02-28 00:00:00.000 2015-01-29 00:00:00.000 2015-03-30 00:00:00.000
```

That is, `ARCurrDue` should be the same day and month as `AnnualReviewDate`, but in the current year, and then the other columns are plus and minus 30 days from that?

You'll note I've included a 29th February in the sample so you can see what's computed for it (you should always think about what the requirement is for such dates and include them in sample data)

---

The magic here is using this expression to reset a date's year to the current one, without affecting the month and day (except for Feb 29):

```
DATEADD(year,DATEDIFF(year,AnnualReviewDate,GETDATE())
       ,AnnualReviewDate)
```

The inner expression (`DATEDIFF`) is "how many year boundaries have passed since `AnnualReviewDate`". The outer expression then adds that same number of whole years onto `AnnualReviewDate`. Note that this same expression even works if `AnnualReviewDate` is a date in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on including exceptions.  I'd taken them into consideration, but not thought to include them and their results in my sample.  I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use integer operations in a `DATETIME` calculation. Do this instead:

```
DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Now),MONTH(DATEADD(M,-1,o.AnnualReviewDate)),DAY(o.AnnualReviewDate)) AS ARDateMin30
```